# How i can get needest line " DBInstanceIdentifier" from Json output with jq or other tools

Tags: json, jq

this is Json: I try to use

```
jq -r '.[] | .DBSnapshotIdentifier'
```

But it doesn't work for me

```
{
    "DBSnapshots": [
        {
            "DBSnapshotIdentifier": "auto-lims-final-snapshot",
            "DBInstanceIdentifier": "auto-lims",
            "SnapshotCreateTime": "2018-08-15T09:59:23.332000+00:00",
            "Engine": "postgres",
            "AllocatedStorage": 50,
            "Status": "available",
            "Port": 5432,
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2a",
            "VpcId": "vpc-e799fc8f",
            "InstanceCreateTime": "2018-04-09T08:28:03.565000+00:00",
            "MasterUsername": "postgres",
            "EngineVersion": "9.6.6",
            "LicenseModel": "postgresql-license",
            "SnapshotType": "manual",
            "OptionGroupName": "default:postgres-9-6",
            "PercentProgress": 100,
            "StorageType": "gp2",
            "Encrypted": false,
            "DBSnapshotArn": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-2:833682533595:snapshot:auto-lims-final-snapshot",
            "IAMDatabaseAuthenticationEnabled": false,
            "ProcessorFeatures": [],
            "DbiResourceId": "db-ZL5T2TA2PJVG6CVOJRO7HUOAXQ",
            "TagList": [
                {
                    "Key": "Environment",
                    "Value": "auto"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Application",
                    "Value": "LIMS"
                }
            ],
            "SnapshotTarget": "region"
        },
        {
            "DBSnapshotIdentifier": "automation-lims-before-postgres-12-5",
            "DBInstanceIdentifier": "automation-lims",
            "Engine": "postgres",
            "AllocatedStorage": 500,
            "Status": "available",
            "Port": 5432,
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2b",
            "VpcId": "vpc-09fa88d2884ee2083",
            "InstanceCreateTime": "2019-12-26T11:19:41.947000+00:00",
            "MasterUsername": "lims",
            "EngineVersion": "9.6.20",
            "LicenseModel": "postgresql-license",
            "SnapshotType": "manual",
            "OptionGroupName": "default:postgres-9-6",
            "PercentProgress": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

How I can get only nested lines.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to select the `DBSnapshots` object, try:

```
.DBSnapshots[] | .DBSnapshotIdentifier
```

This will output:

```
"auto-lims-final-snapshot"
"automation-lims-before-postgres-12-5"
```

As you can try [in this online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/AsK1JhgOa6)

---

To include the `.TagList.Key` we can add the following:

```
.DBSnapshots[] | .DBSnapshotIdentifier, .TagList[]?.Key
```

This will now output

```
"auto-lims-final-snapshot"
"Environment"
"Application"
"automation-lims-before-postgres-12-5"
```

As you can try [in this online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-9xfRJ_K-S)

---

If you'd like the `DBSnapshotIdentifier` to be on the same line as the `TagList` we can use string interpolation like so:

```
.DBSnapshots[] | "\(.DBSnapshotIdentifier) - \(.TagList[]?.Key)"
```

Thiis will output:

```
"auto-lims-final-snapshot - Environment"
"auto-lims-final-snapshot - Application"
```

As [this demo](https://jqplay.org/s/lbmGboH9uY) demostrates

---

The `.[]?` from the above command mean:

> Like `.[]`, but no errors will be output if `.` is not an array or object.

More information [in JQ's documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#.%5B%5D?)

Comment: Please add the desired output to your question.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. It's work. But if i need to get both Key from TagList, what should i do? I try this, but it is not work jq -r '.DBSnapshots[] | .DBSnapshotIdentifier , .TagList[0].["Key"]' and it give with output key parameter null. 
Looks like:
"Environment"
null

Comment: Please see my edit @Andrew

Comment: Thank you, it's work. But can you explain what record "?" means?

Comment: I've changed my edit with some info, and a link to there docs. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Okey thanks. I am sorry but i have one more questions, how i can generate output of .DBSnapshotIdentifier and .TagList[]?.Key in 2 column, for example,
"auto-lims-final-snapshot" - "Environment"